# is it possible to .index a repeated item?

Tags: python

Is it possible to `.index` a repeated item? for example in mylist=[1,2,**7**,8,**7**,12] how can I `.index` the second 7?

`mylist.index(7)` just gives me the place of the first seven.
How can i get the placenumber of the second seven?

```
#### SPY GAME: Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order

     spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) --> True
     spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) --> True
     spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) --> False
```

```
def spy_game(nums):    ####this only work when the second 0 not in after the 7
    
    while 0 in nums and 7 in nums and nums.count(0)>=2:
        if nums.index(7)>nums.index(0):
            return True 
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a string using only 0s and 7s from the input list then you can just search for '007' in that string.

Like this:

```
def spy_game(n: list[int]) -> bool:
    return '007' in ''.join(map(str, (v for v in n if v in {0, 7})))

print(spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]))
print(spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]))
print(spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]))
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
False
```

**Option:**

If you don't want to build strings then just use the integers as follows:

```
def spy_game(n: list[int]) -> bool:
    jb = (0, 0, 7)
    t = [v for v in n if v in {0, 7}]
    for _t in zip(t, t[1:], t[2:]):
        if _t == jb:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: I think this will fail for [0,7,0,7], not sure if it should or not fail for this though...

Comment: @SiP Unless I've misinterpreted OP's requirements then [0,7,0,7] should return False because there is no uninterrupted 007 sequence

Comment: I'm not sure what's the expected result for [0,7,0,7] either, but the in the second example given the 007 is interrupted by other numbers and the function should yield True. I would assume an extra 7 wouldn't be different than an extra 5. Can't be sure though

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it with slicing:

```
a = [0, 0, 7, 1, 5, 6]
b = [0, 7, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 5, ]
c = [7, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6]
d = [0, 7, 0, 7]


def spy_game(l: list[int]) -> bool:
    try:
        ind1 = l.index(0)
        ind2 = l[ind1 + 1:].index(0)
        ind3 = l[ind1 + ind2 + 1:].index(7)  # can replace with if 7 in l[ind1+ind2:]
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


print(spy_game(a))
print(spy_game(b))
print(spy_game(c))
print(spy_game(d))
```

notice that if the value doesn't exist in the list .index will raise a ValueError

Comment: No need to slice... Just use `index` properly.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to use ‘index’ “properly”?

Comment: Should be obvious if you know what it offers. Have you read its documentation?

Answer (score -1):

As the comments already suggest, there are easier ways to do so. However, for your specific question, you could use:

```py
mylist=[1,2,7,8,7,12]
[i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x == 7]
>>> [2,4]
```

By using a list generator looping over the pairs (index, item) in `mylist`, you can check whether the item is equal to 7, and if so, save the index of that item.